# TinyMCE 5: How can I modify formats?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

How can I modify the entries under "Formats" menu in the TinyMCE config settings. I just want to remove the first 4 entries (Heading, Inline..., see picture below). I didn't find anything in the official documentation about that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove the default/standard formats you need to set the `style_formats_merge` configuration option to `false`:

```
style_formats_merge: false
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#style_formats_merge

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle showing this in action: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/U0haab

Comment: But what if I only want to disable some default formats? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would find the default settings for that in the source code of TinyMCE and grab the parts you want and add them to your `style_formats` configuration option.